# Error sending mail with System.Web.Mail

Tags: .net, email, exchange-server

An older application using System.Web.Mail is throwing an exception on emails coming from *hr@domain.com*. Other addresses appear to be working correctly. We changed our mail server to Exchange 2007 when the errors started, so I assume that is where the problem is. Does anyone know what is happening?

Here is the exception and stack trace:

> System.Web.HttpException: Could not access 'CDO.Message' object. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040212): The transport lost its connection to the server.
>   
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.RuntimeType.InvokeDispMethod(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Object target, Object[] args, Boolean[] byrefModifiers, Int32 culture, String[] namedParameters)
>      at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] args, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParameters)
>      at System.Web.Mail.LateBoundAccessHelper.CallMethod(Object obj, String methodName, Object[] args)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Web.Mail.LateBoundAccessHelper.CallMethod(Object obj, String methodName, Object[] args)
>      at System.Web.Mail.CdoSysHelper.Send(MailMessage message)
>      at System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.Send(MailMessage message)
>      at ProcessEmail.Main()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's a tutorial](http://www.systemwebmail.com/faq/4.2.3.aspx) for diagnosing those exceptions (a very common one with a lot of meanings).

Comment: Link does not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Does you client's host machine have permission to send mail via the Exchange Sever?

Comment: Yes, other emails are sent without problems.